# cypress test webservice response (xml)

Tags: javascript, cypress

Is there a simple way to test API calls and test the response of that calls? For now we do stuck at a simple xml response from within the reponse itself. We like to use xpath (cypress plugin) to crawl the xml like:

```
cy.request(`${DOCUMENT_FACADE}`).then((response) => {
  //response is a valid JSON and its body property holds a string (xml)  

  cy.get(response.body).xpath("//*[name() = 'myName']") //this fails by "Not a DOM Object"
  
  //Then we tried to give it a DOM object
  var parser = new DOMParser(),
      doc = parser.parseFromString(response.body, 'text/xml');
  cy.get(doc).xpath("//*[name() = 'myName']").should('have.length', 1) //fails with "expected undefined to have a length of 1 but got 0
});
```

Maybe we totally got something wrong about this quite important part of testing I assume.

Comment: You can maybe skip out on `cy` commands and just use BBD assertions instead.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need the DOMParser, otherwise you're just chopping up a string which xpath won't do too well.

But `cy.get(doc)` is using the DOM as a selector on the previously loaded page (which is not loaded).

You might get it done with `cy.wrap(doc)`, which wraps that whole document and passes it to `.xpath()`.

Or you might need to extract the body first `cy.wrap(doc).its('body').xpath()`.